# iOS11 JB debugserver Failed to get connection from a remote gdb process

Tags: ios, jailbreak

So there is a jailbreak for iOS11 without substrate/cydia.
Now I want to run debugserver after jb the device.

I already signed with enough entitlements I think:

```
-bash-3.2# jtool --ent debugserver 
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>platform-application</key>
        <true/>
        <key>com.apple.backboardd.debugapplications</key>
        <true/>
        <key>com.apple.backboardd.launchapplications</key>
        <true/>
        <key>com.apple.diagnosticd.diagnostic</key>
        <true/>
        <key>com.apple.frontboard.debugapplications</key>
        <true/>
        <key>com.apple.frontboard.launchapplications</key>
        <true/>
        <key>com.apple.springboard.debugapplications</key>
        <true/>
        <key>com.apple.springboard.launchapplications</key>
        <true/>
        <key>com.apple.security.network.client</key>
        <true/>
        <key>com.apple.security.network.server</key>
        <true/>
        <key>run-unsigned-code</key>
        <true/>
        <key>get-task-allow</key>
        <true/>
        <key>task_for_pid-allow</key>
        <true/>
        <key>com.apple.system-task-ports</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

However when trying to `debugserver *:1234 -a UnityExample`, it always shows

```
Attaching to process UnityExample...
Listening to port 1234 for a connection from *...
Failed to get connection from a remote gdb process.
```

If I change the ip to iPhone IP, like `debugserver 192.168.1.157:1234 -a UnityExample`, it can actually wait:

```
Attaching to process UnityExample...
Listening to port 1234 for a connection from 192.168.1.157...
```

But apparently, it will only allow connection from the device, so using mac's lldb won't work.

I checked the kernel log, it prints:

```
Dec 27 10:21:54 iPhone1111 debugserver[564] <Notice>: 1 +0.000000 sec [0234/0303]: ::listen or ::bind failed err = 0x00000000
```

What did I miss? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same happens with me.

I get around this by:

- connecting the device to the mac with USB
- Using usbmuxd to for example forward local port 1234 on mac to remote
  1234 on device
- then run debugserver localhost:1234 -a pid
- and in lldb: process connect connect://localhost:1234

This should work. Unfortunately I can only debug my own apps. Debugging Chrome.app for example starts well and works as long as i'm on the initial paused state, but the minute I resume it fails with EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: Does usbmuxd refer to `iproxy`? Can you give the commend of the proxy? I'm not sure which should be source and destination.

Comment: Download usbmuxd from: 
http://cgit.sukimashita.com/usbmuxd.git/snapshot/usbmuxd-1.0.8.tar.gz and decompress it. Put both files tcprelay.py and usbmux.py in same folder. cd to that folder and run command: /tcprelay.py -t 1234:1234.

Comment: Thank you sir. Can usbmuxd be replaced with iproxy? I plan next week to give a try again.

Comment: Same thing happens to me, even with usbmuxd

Answer (score 2):

Delete the Debugserver file
com.apple.security.network.server
com.apple.security.network.client
seatbelt-profiles
These three Settings, and then re-sign the DebugServer.

Answer (score 0):

On your jailbroken device, ssh into device and:

`/Developer/usr/bin/debugserver 127.0.0.1:6666 -a 1393`

I got the same error you reported when I used `*:6666`

Have you tried this article:

https://kov4l3nko.github.io/blog/2016-04-27-debugging-ios-binaries-with-lldb/

It explains connecting to a jailbroken iOS device over USB, sending files to a device, ssh into a device and getting your debugger (lldb) setup.